# Modelling taggable items in database

Tags: sql, database-design, tags, many-to-many

I am storing tags to posts as a many-to-many relationship, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-des/7296873#7296873).

I now want to extend tags to be able to tag entities other than posts. I have all these in tables named posts, links, articles, etc. Should I opt for:

```
tags_items

tag_id | item_id | item_type
-----------------------------
1        2         post
1        42        link
3        7         article
```

Or create multiple tables

```
tags_posts
tag_id | post_id 

tags_links
tag_id | link_id 

tags_article
tag_id | article_id
```

This forces me to create a new table for every entity I want to tag, but it makes it easier for me to enforce referential integrity.

What are advantages and disadvantages to each approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the two choices I would prefer the second. As you say, it makes R.I. much easier. Another option is to super-type your taggable items. They would need to share an ID scheme, but assuming that the IDs are all **completely** internal (as any good surrogate key should be) that shouldn't be an issue.

```
Taggable_Items
    tag_item_id INT (PK)

Posts
    post_id    INT (PK, FK to tag_item_id in Taggable_Items)
    posted_by  INT (FK to your Users table or whatever)
    post_text  VARCHAR(MAX)
    ...

Links
    link_id      INT (PK, FK to tag_item_id in Taggable_Items)
    url          VARCHAR(1000)
    description  VARCHAR(MAX)
    ...

Tags
    tag_id  INT (PK)
    name    VARCHAR(20)

Tagged_Items
    tag_item_id (PK, FK to tag_item_id in Taggable_Items)
    tag_id      (PK, FK to tag_id in Tags)
```

I hope that's clear enough. Please post a comment if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should take your first option one step further.  Instead of item_type as a varchar or char it should be a foreign key to a table of itemtypes.