# ER diagram: entity → attribute → attribute

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I have to create a ER diagram for this situation:

There are some houses (with own ID) and each house has some attributes like the position of the house and the price. The position has a valuation like the price and I have a list of evaluation.

I have create an entity for the houses with the position attribute and the price attribute but I'm not able to link the position and the price attribute with own valuation.

The schema is this:

[image]

Have you some idea to solve it, without to delete the `list possibile valuation` entity? Thank you very much!

I wish to maintain the information house in an unique entity and the evaluation in another entity. Because my goal is to have one table for all the evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a one-to-many relationship? This way, you would have the valuation ID in house's table, and both entities will remain in separated tables.

There's a good example in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145321/one-to-many-relationship-in-database-design-concept).