# What is the best approach to mapping between two tables with one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Is it best to create third table with primary key of each table as foreign key ? or add foreign key to first table?
For example student table and project table each project has many students.

Comment: You dont need 3rd table if it is one to many, if it was many to many you would.  You just put a FK in the projects table to the StudentID in the student table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [one to many relationship in database - design concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145321/one-to-many-relationship-in-database-design-concept)

Comment: Another duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you indeed have a 1-many relationship, then you add a foreign key to the first table.  For instance:

```
create table students (
     . . . 
    projectId int not null references project(projectId)
);
```

The `not null` makes this *1*-many.  In most cases, you probably want 0/1-many.  If so, then remove the `not null` constraint.

You would only introduce a third table (known as an "association table", "junction table", "cross table" and other names) if students could work on more than one project.

Note that you might want a third table if the student-project relationship can change over time.  At any given time, a student works on one project, but over time, if the student can work on more than one.

Comment: thnaks @Gordan  No ,no student can work on more than one project

Answer (score 2):

If it is one to many just add new column as foreign key (projectId) in student table