# Many to Many relation DB design

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, schema, entity-relationship

I have a table named `config`. Each `config` row has a list of `services` tied to it.
There are a total of 10 specific `services` available.

How should I design the schema? The `config` schema already exists.
This is my idea, but not sure if it is the right way.

```
config
===================
config_id primary key  
col-1  
col-2  
...  
col-n
```

I am planning to introduce a new table.

```
serviceconfigmap 
======================================== 
config-id # foreign key to config table  
svc_id    # service identifier
```

The problem with this approach is that, the `serviceconfigmap` table will duplicate the `svc_id` column for each `config-id`

Is this the right approach? Any better idea is welcome

========================================

**EDIT**

I understand that I incorrectly termed my requirement as `One-to-Many` instead of `Many-to-Many`. Edited my question.

Each config can have multiple services and same servoce can be shared among different configs.

Comment: This isn't one-to-many, but many-to-many (one config might have multiple services, and one service might belong to many configs, if I understood you correctly). Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de/7296873#7296873

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are designing for `Many-To-Many` relationship, since config has many services and services can contain on different config.

You need to have three tables for this, `Config`, `Service` and `MappingTable`

```
Config
=========
Config_ID         => unique
Config_Name
.....

Service
=========
Service_ID        => unique
Service_Name
.....

ConfigServiceMap
==================
Config_ID         
Service_ID
.....
```

Comment: I will be querying this table based on `config_id`. So putting an index on this column alone would suffice?

Answer (score 2):

If it is purely a `1->many` I would only add a `config_id` to the table `services`

So your services tables would look something like

```
service_id (primary key)
config_id (foreign key)
col1
col2
...
coln
```

You only need a mapping table if it is `many<->many`

**EDIT**

Then this is not a one to many, but a many to many. You might want to stick to the many to many table you had, but put a primary key on columns (config_id, service_id) as to not duplicate the service per config entry.

Comment: If you add `config_id` to `services` table, how once config can have multiple services? Different config can share the same service as well.

Comment: Why should I put a primary key on both columns? I want to query this table based on `config_id`. So, putting an index on `config_id` column would suffice?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY, not index. The primary key will ensure that you cannot insert the same entry twice. so you cannot insert the combination confid_id = 1 and service_id = 1 twice.

Comment: If I put  a primary key on the 2 column group, will the query based on `config_id` be faster? `SELECT service_id from configservicemap where config_id = 1`

Comment: Slightly, as it might use the key if you put it in order (config_id,service_id) as order does make a difference. you might still want to put an index on it too. Test to see what the difference in performance is.

Answer (score 1):

The 'config' table as it stands currently contravenes first normal form in that it has repeating groups (one field for each service). What happens when a new service is defined? You will have to change the structure of the 'config' table. Thus a 'join table' between configurations and services is the standard way to go.

If one service can belong to several configurations, then a join table becomes a must.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right , you will need third table to store foreign key of both tables.Hope that helps

Comment: In this case, one `service_id` belong to one `config_id`. I want one `config_id` to have multiple `service_id`. Also 2 different `config_id` can share the same `service_id`.