# MySQL Match single number from stored checkbox implode

Tags: php, mysql

Not sure if i labeled this question clearly, however, i have a MySQL table with a column `zones`. This column holds the values of a checkbox array that has been run through PHP's implode like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
    $zones = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);
}
```

This saves the data in a string format like `2,3,4,5`.

I'd like to create a query to basically match any number in that individual column. So far my query looks like:

```
$zoneId = '2';
SELECT * FROM $alert_table WHERE `zones` LIKE $zoneId AND `time_created` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1;
```

It works perfectly if the column only has 1 number. But fails if the column has the string `2,3,4,5`.

Any help is appreciated, i am not opposed to a change in method of storing the checkbox values if their is a better alternative.

Comment: Do **NOT** combine multiple values in a single field. This is a very bad design.

Comment: Nooooo dont store things in something seperated lists in a single column. ___It causes you to have to ask these kind of questions___ as it makes the data ___almost___ impossible to process

Comment: This post should be very helpful to you ..   You need a table that just stores the checkbox value and a **seperate** pivot table to link those values to other items.  This is a `one-to-many` relationship:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I understand the flaw in my table now, thank you. I need to store the zone data separately ( Preferably a separate table ).

Comment: @ShateelAhmed See my comment. I understand the flaw in table design and understand the fix. Regardless performing the query with a `LIKE`search would return 2, however the `ORDER BY "id" LIMIT 1 would return a single item which is what i need.

Comment: Looks like you need to use regexp (RLIKE):  "SELECT ... WHERE zones RLIKE '(^|,)$zoneID(,|$)' ..."