# Creating Table Type with another type (user defined) in SQL Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a type with another type like below.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PropertyImage] AS TABLE
(
    [PropertyImage] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [PropertyType] [NVARCHAR](500) NULL
)

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Properties] AS TABLE
(
    [Id] INT,
    [UserId] INT,
    [PropertyImageList] [dbo].[PropertyImage]
)
```

I get this error:

> The column "PropertyImageList" does not have a valid data type. A column cannot be of a user-defined table type.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: "A column cannot be of a user-defined table type." message is very clear. You can't do it.

Comment: Yes, that'y why looking for some alternate.

Comment: You want to create a one-to-many relationship, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de) SO post.

Comment: The fact that you are trying to use a table-value data type for a column implies that you are trying to store multiple values in a single entity. The solution, therefore, is one of 2 things; Add more columns to your table is it is a 1-to-1 relationship or create a new table if it's 1-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an XML column with a schema.

```
 CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [PropertyImageXMLSchema] AS
 N' <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
          <element name="Image">  
           <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element minOccurs="0" name="PropertyImage" type="string"/>
                <element minOccurs="0" name="PropertyType" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
           </complexType>
          </element>
        </schema>  ';
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [Properties]  (
        [Id] int,
        [UserId] int,
        [PropertyImageList] XML(PropertyImageXMLSchema)
    );
   GO
    INSERT INTO [Properties] (Id, UserId,PropertyImageList)
    VALUES (1,1,
    N'<Image>
        <PropertyImage>test image 1 </PropertyImage>
        <PropertyType>test type 1</PropertyType>
    </Image>
    <Image>
        <PropertyImage>test image 2 </PropertyImage>
        <PropertyType>test type 2</PropertyType>
    </Image>'
    );
```

Comment: This is more of a comment, not an answer. I would suggest expanding on this to explain your answer. Give an example, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TYPE TypeName FROM nvarchar(max) 

CREATE TABLE Test(Test_Name varchar(50), Test_Data TypeName)
--Custom Type Table 

CREATE TYPE customTypeTable AS Table (name varchar(100), age int, location TypeName)
```

For more details please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/working-with-user-defined-types-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Can you fit your solution in my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need user defined types at all?  Is there a problem with the typical SQL solution of two tables?

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].Properties (
    PropertyId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    UserId INT
);

CREATE TABLE PropertyImages (
    PropertyImageId INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    PropertyId INT NOT NULL,
    PropertyImage NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    PropertyType [NVARCHAR(500) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_PropertyImages_PropertyId FOREIGN KEY (PropertyId) REFERENCES Properties(PropertyId)
);
```

Comment: Yes, I have a property table and it's images in separate table. Now requirement is to save a list of properties along with images in 1 DB call.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi . . . Then use the `PropertyImages` table as described in this answer.