# How to sort my products within multiple categories ? Its an offline Project

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table on my MySQL database. And My Tables like above.

Note: Its an offline and old script.

My Products Table ;

```
|  ID   |  ProductName  |  ProductCategory  |
---------------------------------------------
|  1    |  Example Name |  1,2,3,4,5,6,7    |
---------------------------------------------
|  2    |  Example Name |  1,2,10,11,12     |
---------------------------------------------
```

And My Query is like below for list my products by category.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products where FIND_IN_SET('".$catid."', ProductCategory)");
```

I can sort them for desc or asc but i want to sort them manually like i desired.

i need an idea.

Comment: Please **stop** here and read over "database normalform/normalisation".. the structure of `ProductCategory` is really bad.. do **not** store somma separated values.. and also be aware that **mysql_* functions are deprecated**

Comment: Its an local computer and working on my customer's store. I know  mysql_* is deprecated but i dont want to waste my time on this project. and we dont care about sql injection attacks because system is offline. What is your comment about my Question ?

Answer (score 0):

Your database design violates first normal form. You SHOULDNOT insert multiple values into a column by separating with commas.

Your database schema should look like below

```
create table ProductTable(ProductID integer primary key, ProductName varchar(30));

create table CategoryTable(CategoryID integer primary key, CategoryName varchar(30));

create table ProductCategoryRelationTable(ProductID integer, CategoryID integer);
```

Why we created ProductCategoryRelationTable is because one Product can have multiple Categories and a category can belong to multiple products (multi multi relationship). Also ProductCategoryRelationTable should have composite primary key on (ProductID,CategoryID) and foreign key constraints with ProductTable and CategoryTable.

Once you have created above tables, try to express your queries around these tables.

Comment: You don't need `ProductCategoryRelationTable`.... Just do `create table ProductTable(ProductID integer primary key, ProductName varchar(30), CategoryID integer);`

Comment: @B001ᛦ And where would you store this many-to-many relation?

Comment: Its an local computer and working on my customer's store. I know  mysql_* is deprecated but i dont want to waste my time on this project. and we dont care about sql injection attacks because system is offline. What is your comment about my Question ?

Comment: You can use some mysql function and obtain the result. But getting result should not be the target. We should always plan for the future use cases. If you create tables as suggested by me, any new requirement in the future can be solved with simple queries. If you keep on using these mysql functions, any new developer who might try to modify your query in the future will definitely face serious issues. Incorrect usage of these functions for such simple use cases will cause unnecessary performance issues.

Comment: @B001ᛦ If a product is having a single category, your solution is correct. But here a product can have multiple categories and a category can be associated with multiple products. When we have multi-to-multi relationship we should use junction table. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de