# Several authors for one book in SQL

Tags: javascript, sqlite, graphql

I have a `books` table and on each row (book) some books have several authors.

Using SQLite I can do this
`CREATE TABLE users (authors text[])`

How can I insert several values to authors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we are looking at here is what is known as a "one to many" relation see [[ link ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de). The idea is that you create the books and then for each author you could link to a book in a table book-authors. Then you join the tables.

Comment: This one looks good. can you please tell me how to insert to it ?

Comment: You can not insert to multiple tables in one **statement** but you can do it in one transaction. It could look something like this.

INSERT INTO books (book_name, release_date) VALUES ('my_book', 2019);
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO book_authors (book_id, author_id) VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, any_author_id);
INSERT INTO book_authors (book_id, author_id) VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, any_other_author_id);

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches, one being "right" and the second being more of a kludge.

If you create several tables

```
Author
  AuthorID (long)
  AuthorName (string)

Book
  BookID (Long)
  BookName (string)

BookAuthors
  BookAuthorID (long)
  BookID (long / external key)
  AuthorID (long / external key)
```

The other approach is list the authors as one long string with some special character (such as the `|` symbol) to separate them.  This approach is much more difficult to search however.