# Store the same Unique Number for different users in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

I have a Employee Table that stores unique Employee numbers in the `emp_no` column.  The thing is if another user or company stores its Employees in the same table and have an employee with the same  number e.g. `1001` that has already been used they cannot store there employee.
WHAT I want to know is should I create a new employee table for each new user or is there a different solution?

Comment: you can make it unique with the company id and emp_no. So there will be an employ id under a  company only one time.  For batter answer, you can include your Employee table screen sort

Comment: Make the primary key be a combination of company ID and EmployeeID. A key can be made up of one or more columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, don't create multiple employees table**

Your case is very standard in the SQL world, it's what we call a 1 to N relationship (or [one to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de)). A company can have many employees but an employee is linked to one company.

You need to create a company table with a unique company id and a company name.
Then, in your employee table, you add a new column with a foreign key constraint to the company id column. 
Finally, in your employee table, set the unique constraint on the couple (emp_no, company_id) so that the unicity constraint represents your real world constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Just to clarify so that I do not make an error with my implementation:  1] Company tb with your parameters (have that already); 2] Foreign key constraint on child employee table ```emp_entity id column``` (have that as on cascade update) 3] Unique constraint on two columns ```emp_number``` and ```emp_entity``` (do not have this yet).  Therefore will the edit on my table look as follows:  ```ALTER TABLE `database`.`employeetable` DROP INDEX `unique_emptb_empno`, ADD UNIQUE `unique_emptb_empno` (`emp_number`, `emp_entity`) USING BTREE;```

Comment: I tested your answer and it works great!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Baxbong's answer is correct, but it doesn't quite go far enough.  You should set up the tables like this:

```
create table companies (
    company_id int auto_increment primary key,
    company_name varchar(255),
    . . .  -- all your other columns
);

create table employees (
    employee_id int auto_increment primary key,
    company_id int not null,
    emp_no varchar(255) not null,
    . . .  -- all your other columns
    constraint unq_employees_company_empno unique (company_id, emp_no),
    constraint fk_employees_company foreign key (company_id) references companies (company_id)
);
```

The important point here is that `employees` has a single primary key column.  This can be used for foreign key references in other tables.