# MySQL modelling task

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

I have next task to do in MySQL:

- We have Accounts, Farms, Customers, and Users
- An account belongs to a Customer
- A User has access to one or more accounts
- A User has access to one or more farms tied to that account
- A farm is tied to one account

Here is ER Model:

[image]

Can someone take a look and check whether I made this correct?

Comment: Suggestion for what?

Comment: Not suggestion, maybe correctness.

Comment: `users` and `customers`, in-order to avoid redundancy have only a single table `users` and add a column named `role` in `users`.

Comment: No, no, users and customers are two different entities.

Comment: right! then this is the relation between `users` and `customers`. `Each customer is a user` and `a user can be a customer`

Comment: I think that user manages customer account.

Comment: add an association between `users` and `customers`

Comment: Did you read the text above the diagram?

Comment: yep, based on the information above I've given you suggestions.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you notice any other mistake?

Answer (score 0):

For this SQL modeling task, you have three types of entity relationships: one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many ([How to implement one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships while designing tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de) for more detail on their implementation).

In your toy model, if "a User has access to one or more accounts," this is modeled as a one-to-many relationship between the user and the accounts, which requires a foreign id on the many side (i.e. every account has a user_id) but user does not have an account_id.

The account-customer relationship appears to be well-modeled, because it is one-to-one (so either table can hold the foreign key), but your one-to-many relations appear to have some errors.

Comment: Where do you think I should use many to many? Can you say what errors in one-to-many?

Comment: But users can access many accounts. Why should user have an account_id?

Comment: @nenad 1) you should model the relationships that you need to. You don't necessarily need to model all kinds of relationships, but I mention all of them for completeness. 2) Please check all your relationships through these lenses (some may be correct but not all); I don't want to give you an easy answer because this looks like a homework question to me

Comment: Can you please review this part of your answer:
"In your toy model, if "a User has access to one or more accounts," this is modeled as a one-to-many relationship between the user and the accounts, which requires a foreign id on the many side (i.e. every account has a user_id) but user does not have an account_id."

Comment: I put foreign id on the many side and user does not have an account_id. I've alredy did it like you sad.

Comment: @nenad This means one user -> many accounts (or, equivalently, each account is related to exactly one user but not the other way around). You may have done this piece correctly, but I urge you to check *all* of your relations.

Comment: Yes, I will. You should have written something useful but thank you in any case.

Comment: @nenad Look at your ***other relations***

Comment: I will. Thank you.