# How to count products to multiple filters

Tags: mysql

**UPDATED**

I like to make product filter module like this one [Online Shop](https://www.argos.co.uk/browse/technology/televisions-and-accessories/televisions/c:30106/) , when you click one of the filters to count current products in other filters

For example if this is frontend and their are checkboxes and their are UNchecked atm

```
Size (group_id)
  10m (option_id: 52) (21 products)
  20m (option_id: 51) (1 product)

Color (group_id)
   Green (option_id: 49) (22 products)
   Black (option_id: 38) (1 product)
```

If a user select 10m (option_id: 52) the filter counter should become like this

```
Size (group_id)
  10m (option_id: 52) (21 products)
  20m (option_id: 51) (1)

Color (group_id)
   Green (option_id: 49) (2)
   Black (option_id: 38) (0)
```

I made one table only for counting where i keep group_id,option_id,product_id,category_id,manufacturer_id

I make query that count products to filter but problem is that i cant return other filter counter (option_id: 38) in same category and manufacturer counter for all manufacturer in same category , any ideas how to make it ?

```
SELECT sd.*, COUNT(sd.product_id) FROM filter_counter sd WHERE sd.product_id IN (SELECT c.product_id FROM filter_counter c WHERE c.option_id IN (52) AND c.category_id = 127) AND sd.category_id = 127 GROUP BY sd.option_id
```

```
CREATE TABLE `filter_counter` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `option_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `filter_counter` (`id`, `group_id`, `option_id`, `product_id`, `category_id`, `manufacturer_id`) VALUES
(1, 33, 52, 5124, 65, 36),
(2, 33, 52, 5124, 127, 36),
(3, 33, 52, 5125, 65, 36),
(4, 33, 52, 5125, 127, 36),
(5, 33, 52, 5138, 65, 36),
(6, 33, 52, 5138, 127, 36),
(7, 33, 52, 5141, 65, 36),
(8, 33, 52, 5141, 127, 36),
(9, 33, 52, 5146, 65, 36),
(10, 33, 52, 5146, 127, 36),
(11, 33, 52, 5147, 65, 36),
(12, 33, 52, 5147, 127, 36),
(13, 33, 52, 5148, 65, 36),
(14, 33, 52, 5148, 127, 36),
(15, 33, 52, 5149, 65, 36),
(16, 33, 52, 5149, 127, 36),
(17, 33, 52, 5150, 65, 36),
(18, 33, 52, 5150, 127, 36),
(19, 33, 52, 5151, 65, 36),
(20, 33, 52, 5151, 127, 36),
(21, 33, 52, 5152, 65, 36),
(22, 33, 52, 5152, 127, 36),
(23, 33, 52, 5153, 65, 36),
(24, 33, 52, 5153, 127, 36),
(25, 33, 52, 5154, 65, 36),
(26, 33, 52, 5154, 127, 36),
(27, 33, 52, 5155, 65, 36),
(28, 33, 52, 5155, 127, 36),
(29, 33, 52, 5156, 65, 36),
(30, 33, 52, 5156, 127, 36),
(31, 33, 52, 5157, 65, 36),
(32, 33, 52, 5157, 127, 36),
(33, 33, 52, 7042, 65, 38),
(34, 33, 52, 7042, 127, 38),
(35, 33, 52, 7048, 65, 38),
(36, 33, 52, 7048, 127, 38),
(37, 33, 52, 7124, 65, 0),
(38, 33, 52, 7124, 127, 0),
(39, 32, 49, 7185, 65, 0),
(40, 32, 49, 7185, 127, 0),
(41, 32, 49, 7517, 65, 39),
(42, 32, 49, 7517, 127, 39),
(43, 32, 49, 7518, 65, 39),
(44, 32, 49, 7518, 127, 39),
(45, 32, 49, 7538, 65, 39),
(46, 32, 49, 7538, 127, 39),
(47, 32, 49, 7657, 65, 39),
(48, 32, 49, 7657, 127, 39),
(49, 32, 49, 7658, 65, 39),
(50, 32, 49, 7658, 127, 39),
(51, 32, 49, 7797, 65, 21),
(52, 32, 49, 7797, 127, 21),
(53, 32, 49, 7798, 65, 21),
(54, 32, 49, 7798, 127, 21),
(55, 32, 49, 7799, 65, 21),
(56, 32, 49, 7799, 127, 21),
(57, 32, 49, 7800, 65, 21),
(58, 32, 49, 7800, 127, 21),
(59, 32, 49, 7801, 65, 21),
(60, 32, 49, 7801, 127, 21),
(61, 32, 49, 7802, 65, 21),
(62, 32, 49, 7802, 127, 21),
(63, 32, 49, 7803, 65, 21),
(64, 32, 49, 7803, 127, 21),
(65, 32, 49, 7804, 65, 21),
(66, 32, 49, 7804, 127, 21),
(67, 32, 49, 7805, 65, 21),
(68, 32, 49, 7805, 127, 21),
(69, 32, 49, 7806, 65, 21),
(70, 32, 49, 7806, 127, 21),
(71, 32, 49, 7807, 65, 21),
(72, 32, 49, 7807, 127, 21),
(73, 32, 49, 7808, 65, 21),
(74, 32, 49, 7808, 127, 21),
(75, 32, 49, 7809, 65, 21),
(76, 32, 49, 7809, 127, 21),
(77, 32, 49, 7810, 65, 21),
(78, 32, 49, 7810, 127, 21),
(79, 29, 38, 7811, 65, 21),
(80, 29, 38, 7811, 127, 21),
(81, 32, 49, 8020, 65, 21),
(82, 32, 49, 8020, 127, 21),
(83, 33, 52, 8020, 65, 21),
(84, 33, 52, 8020, 127, 21),
(85, 32, 49, 8021, 65, 21),
(86, 32, 49, 8021, 127, 21),
(87, 33, 51, 8021, 65, 21),
(88, 33, 51, 8021, 127, 21),
(89, 33, 52, 8021, 65, 21),
(90, 33, 52, 8021, 127, 21);
```

[My database and query example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2239a0/1)

Comment: Can you write your text more concisely? I'd like to help but am having trouble understanding your question

Comment: *for example if i have one product_id 8020 with two options ( options_id 49 and 52 ) when user select option 49 count must show 1 product in option 49 and 1 product in option 52* Absolutely unclear... Why product 8021 is ignored? Why option 52 is counted whereas user does not select it?

Comment: @CasperDijkstra i update question

Comment: @Akina i update question

Comment: Can u try adding sd.Product_id in  group by clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example if this is frontend and their are checkboxes and their are UNchecked atm
>
> ```
> Size (group_id)
>  10m (option_id: 52) (21 products)
>  20m (option_id: 51) (1 product)
>
> Color (group_id)
>   Green (option_id: 49) (22 products)
>   Black (option_id: 38) (1 product)
> ```

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN option_id = 52 THEN product_id END) p52,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN option_id = 51 THEN product_id END) p51,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN option_id = 49 THEN product_id END) p49,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN option_id = 38 THEN product_id END) p38
FROM filter_counter;
```

> If a user select 10m (option_id: 52) the filter counter should become like this
>
> ```
> Size (group_id)
>  10m (option_id: 52) (21 products)
>  20m (option_id: 51) (1)
>
> Color (group_id)
>   Green (option_id: 49) (2)
>   Black (option_id: 38) (0)
> ```

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN option_id = 52 THEN product_id END) p52,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN option_id = 51 THEN product_id END) p51,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN option_id = 49 THEN product_id END) p49,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN option_id = 38 THEN product_id END) p38
FROM filter_counter
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_id
       FROM filter_counter
       WHERE option_id IN (52) ) filter1 USING (product_id);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=222eab8eb3fb882c86d95a7fe5cf70e1)

If user checks additional filter in the same group then the next value is added into the condition. For example, if he checks `option_id = 51` which is in the same group with `option_id = 52` then filtering subquery become

```sql
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_id
       FROM filter_counter
       WHERE option_id IN (52, 51) ) filter1 USING (product_id)
```

If user checks additional filter in another group then additional `filterX` subquery added. For example, if he checks `option_id = 49` then the next subquery added to the query:

```sql
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_id
       FROM filter_counter
       WHERE option_id IN (49) ) filter2 USING (product_id)
```

---

> is there any way output to become one per line ?

```sql
SELECT options.option_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN filter_counter.option_id = options.option_id 
                           THEN product_id 
                           END) option_count
FROM filter_counter
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT option_id
             FROM filter_counter ) options
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT product_id
       FROM filter_counter
       WHERE option_id IN (52) ) filter1 USING (product_id)
GROUP BY options.option_id;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fa423b9fd21d4b938ccce663cddd77fa)

Comment: I appreciate your help and this is almost what im looking for only the output result wont fit to my code, is there any way output to become one per line ? like this one http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2239a0/1  , i really have no idea how to rework your query to become like this

Comment: @Ivan *is there any way output to become one per line ?* Updated.

Comment: I just notice now if you select option_id 51 will update count for option_id 52 but they are in same group and should be not updated like if user want to see products with 10m and 20m i will display 21 products from option_id 52 and 1 with option_id 51 , like the link here if you select screen size https://www.argos.co.uk/browse/technology/televisions-and-accessories/televisions/c:30106/   is it possible ? becasue i tried to add AND group_id != 33 but is not working

Comment: *if you select option_id 51 will update count for option_id 52* I don't understand this phrase. Add a query with this addition at the end of the fiddle and provide the link.

Comment: its become like when they are in same group : show products with Size: 10m and 20m, when they are in different group: show products Size: 10m who have color Green.   Here is a fiddle  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d30bcfd6bc3ef3920654ae84d5b6287b

Comment: See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea3d586cb642c485d524db0cde5b2602). I add some explanations. You need in something else? Sorry, I cannot understand your need in this case.

Comment: Sorry for my bad logic and english , here i what i need https://www.argos.co.uk/browse/technology/televisions-and-accessories/televisions/c:30106/ : Select one or all options from "Screen size range (in)" the counter for selected and none selected options in group "Screen size range (in)" are not change no matter how many option are selected in this group "Screen size range (in)"  BUT all other group and option count is updated

Comment: In my case when you select option_id 51 count should look like option_id(38)  0,
option_id(49)  1,
option_id(51)  1,
option_id(52)  21

Comment: *option_id(52) 21* o_O Why? option 52 is NOT selected.

Comment: they are in same group (33)  like argos filter where they are in same group "Screen size range (in)"

Comment: Initial question tells nothing about groups. So counthing while taking into account both separate options and options groups is out of the question and must be asked separately.

Comment: Im really sorry if i forget to mentioned about group, do you like me to open a new question about group separate counting ?

Comment: I think this is logical. In the new question, give a link to this question.

Comment: I did a new question, if you like to help again here is the link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65086668/how-to-count-products-to-multiple-filters-separated-by-group

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I cannot make a lot of sense out of your **example:**

> for example if i have one product_id 8020 with two options (
> options_id 49 and 52 ) when user select option 49 count must show 1
> product in option 49 and 1 product in option 52

But following your title, *ONE TO MANY* and your **problem:**

> But the problem is coming when you have to select one or more filters
> how to count how many products are sill enable to combinate between
> filters ?

I will try to explain with a generalised answer.

First you have to figure out *what* makes a product able to fit in the two filters you have selected. If you *SELECT filter_id* `'1'` and `'5'`

```
(1, 32, 49, 8020, 65, 21)

(5, 32, 49, 8021, 65, 21)
```

We can see that the only thing they differ in is the `product_id` so if you want to select all products who share everything except their `product_id` you can do a very basic `SELECT product_id, COUNT(product_id) AS total FROM filter_counter WHERE group_id = 32 AND category_id = 65`

But if you want to make the entire solution based on a *ONE TO MANY* as mentioned in your title I would suggest you create a new table for your products and make every product have a filter id instead. Then you can count the amount of products who share the same filter. You can read more about it in this stackoverflow question: [How to implement one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships while designing tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de)

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE 'product' (
   product_id PRIMARY KEY,
   filter_id int REFERENCES filter_counter(id),
   ... More info for product
)
```

Comment: @Ivan so this answer did not answer your question?

Comment: i appreciate your help is close to what im looking for