# How to count products in multiple filters?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

[This is my fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ejBiMaqt)

I've got Product table with one-to-many relations to Platform table and Region table. There are also 2x many-to-many relations (Genre table and ProductType). Now for each of these tables (Platform, Region, Genre, ProductType) I want to count products accordingly. This is what I've achieved so far:

[image: tables]

However I want filtering to work like [at this online store](https://www.argos.co.uk/browse/technology/video-games-and-consoles/pc-gaming/pc-games/c:30005/). If I select i.e. Genre - 'Action', the rest of the tables should update products count. Same if I select i.e. 'XBOX ONE' as Platform, the rest should show current count of products available at those filters. This is the same problem as [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64670519/how-to-count-products-to-multiple-filters), however I don't know how to achieve same with one-to-many and many-to-many relations. I need guide from beggining. Thanks!

EDIT: This is expected output after selecting Genre - 'Action'
[image: expected output]

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're trying to achieve -

[image: for action]

This is for the `Action` category as an example.
Here's the query that i made to achieve this -

```sql
SELECT P.id AS PlatformId, P.name AS PlatformName, COUNT(1) AS ProductCount
FROM Platform P
JOIN Product Prod ON Prod.platformId = P.id
JOIN GenreToProduct GTP ON GTP.B = Prod.id
JOIN Genre G ON GTP.A = G.id
WHERE G.name = 'Action'  -- Replace with the selected Genre
GROUP BY P.id, P.name
ORDER BY P.id ASC;
```

You can change the genre to whatever you like and it should get you the count in it. Here's an updated fiddle for it : https://dbfiddle.uk/05wqKwiE