# Which relationship should be among tables?

Tags: sql

I have a table `Expenses` and relative table `ExpensesCaterory`.

The `Expenses` table can contains a lot of rows of expenses with diferent catergory.

Does it mean that relationship between table are one(expenses) to many(categories)?

**Is it correct on the schema?**

[image]

Comment: Would one expense be mapped to only one category? Or could one expense be categorized under multiple categories too?

Comment: One expense is relative to one category. For exampel amount 2000 is relative to taxi espense

Comment: But it can be a lot of expenses for taxi in table expenses

Comment: It is one to many, so each category has a lot of expenses, but expense has only one category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is one-to-many relationship but should be the other way around, one category to many expenses. Think of it as **one** `ExpenseCaterory` can have **many** `Expense` while **one** `Expense` can only be in **one** `ExpenseCaterory`, as the image in this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)):

**ExpensesCaterory**

```
1 | Taxi Expense
2 | Electricity Expense
3 | Food Expense
4 | Rent Expense
```

**Expenses**

```
1 | 2000 | Taxi Expense
2 | 360 | Taxi Expense
3 | 8500 | Food Expense
4 | 435 | Taxi Expense
3 | 12000| Electricity Expense
```

Here, you can see that "one" category `Taxi Expense` is mapped/related to "many" expenses namely `2000`, `360`, and `435`.

The idea is basically that a record from the "one" side (here is `ExpensesCaterory`) is related to one or more records in the "many" side (here is `Expenses`).

Related reference:

- [How to implement one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships while designing tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de)

Comment: It should be the reverse. The "many" side should be the "Expense" side while the "one" side should be the "ExpenseCaterory". Think of it as _one "ExpenseCaterory" can have many "Expense" but one "Expense" can only be in one "ExpenseCaterory"_.