# How to do Many to Many Relations in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have some trouble,
Data Example:
animal_table:

- id
- name
- desc

---

---

farmer_table:

- id
- name
- desc

---

---

investor_table:

- id
- name
- desc

---

Main Trouble: now i will create Simple CRUD applications, but there is some conditions.
Investors(Many) to Animals(Many)
Farmers(One) to Animals(Many)

how do i create the database Structure for this problems

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook solution to implementing a many-to-many relationship is a mapping table with the IDs of the entities you want to have in the relationship. Each row in this mapping table represents a connection between the two entities. E.g.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE investors_animals (
    animal_id INT NOT NULL,
    investor_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (animal_id, investor_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (animal_id) REFERENCES animal(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (investor_id) REFERENCES investor(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this answer it is shown what you need:
[How to implement one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships while designing tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296846/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-while-de)

For your example it would be something like this:

**Investors(Many) to Animals(Many)**
You need a need Table like investor_animal:

- investor_id
- animal_id

**Farmers(One) to Animals(Many)**
You can give the animal table a farmer_id. So the animal knows who is the farmer.